# How do you view previous Inside Xbox (or any old feed) in the 360's new 'metro' UI?

Tags: xbox-360

In the NXE I could view hints and tips from old Inside Xbox episodes from a history channel.

I can't find this in the new Metro UI - I can view the most recent stories only, but that only ever covers the last month or two and I regularly buy old games and want to view the feed from when they were released.

How do I do this in Metro? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how far back it goes, but you could try the [Inside Xbox YouTube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/InsideXbox). It's possible the videos there go back farther than those available through the dashboard.

Comment: Now they've edited that stuff out as if it was never there. So glad that I'm paying exactly the same as I was before for less content.